# How do I use greenscreen on a blender object?

Tags: modeling, mesh

I'm trying to do a greenscreen effect on a blender object. Basically the way I want it set us is like a television or monitor. Where I can greenscreen it onto an object and have it display a video or an image. I would also like to but it underneath a layer of glass so it will seem like it's part of the mesh.

Comment: Greenscreen is a horrible "real life hack" with Blender you don't have to do that. However, I don't know what your end goal is. Why not just put your movie onto some plane underneath some glass?

Comment: @FrederikSteinmetz I was able to fix the issue, I just used a clever trick with plains